# How do I remove form attributes in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a Form element:

```
$Form=new Zend_Form;
        $Form->setAction($this->view->url(array('controller'=>'auth','action'=>'create'),null,true))
             ->setMethod('post')
             ->setAttrib('id','auth-form')
             ->removeAttrib('enctype');
```

As can be seen I use the removeAttrib method to remove the default enctype. But, when I echo the form I still get:

```
<form id="auth-form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/auth/resetpassword2" method="post">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out. Line 92 of `Zend_Form_Decorator_Form`:

```
if ($method == Zend_Form::METHOD_POST) {
    $this->setOption('enctype', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
}
```

So, if it's post, the enctype is automatically added. You could override the decorator and remove, though I'm not sure if there's anything wrong with having the enctype set.

Comment: Ah yeah, I think this is right answer. You could also just create your own form view helper to override the default one. If the EncType clashes with the JS can't you just change the EncType to match?

Comment: Might be a fix: http://www.talkphp.com/javascript-ajax-e4x/1176-form-enctype-internet-explorer.html

Answer (score 2):

```
$Form->setAttrib('enctype', null);
```

Answer (score 1):

'enctype' is not an attribute in the Zend_Form sense. See the [setEncType()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Form/Zend_Form.html#setEnctype) method. I'm not sure that you can completely remove it without writing the HTML yourself though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is on by default in order for file uploads to work in any case. Note that if you set the `enctype` to `''` you won't be able to upload files via that form.